# Libgdx - rendering many small sprites VS a few big ones

Tags: android, ios, performance, libgdx, rendering

I am working on an effect for my game where I have several (200) stars coming from the edges of the screen, moving towards the middle while fading out.

I would want to render each star on its own (as it's own object) so that the stars can have randoms speed, fade times, size and position. however I'm afraid it might effect older phones greatly in performance, to change the alpha and rendering 200 sprites each frame for up to 20 seconds (I recreate them when they fade out).

As an alternative i could use larger chunks of stars as the same sprite (one image) this means I'll have to sacrifice the random effects and stars will fade out at the same time, which obv won't look as good.

I have no way to test on older phones so I'll ask here, is looping through 200 sprites each frame too much (small images where I alter alpha each frame and position)? is there an alternative that doesn't force me to give up the random behaviour of each star? or do I just have to bite the bullet and render larger images (maybe 3-4 different images with several stars in each)?

Comment: Mid range devices from five years ago would have no problem with this so modern low end devices should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with a [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), a good explanation and tutorial could be found [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html). Basically what you do is have a default model of your sprite (in this case, your star) and then draw it at different positions.

You don't have to sacrifice the random effects that you mention, just have to adapt it to your model so each object can have its fade out effect at the same time. In the appended example, they vary the position of the mesh but I guess you could expand it to allow to vary other parameters.

Also, check [this part](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch%2C-textureregions%2C-and-sprite#performance-tuning) of libgdx wiki where they talk about performance tuning.

Another option is check your app performance (use of cpu, gpu, memory, most of IDE's have tools to measure this) and then compare with old phones performance stats.

However, if you want to include old phones, I guess eventually you will have to test this app in those models.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this example :)